# Grpc Java hot failover with static addresses

Tags: java, grpc, failover, grpc-java

I want to use a hot failover for my grpc client, so if a connection fails, it will failover directly to another server specified at start. I don't want to add an additional external resolver, but directly set all possible service addresses on initialization.
Currently I'm building the channel like this:

```java
ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("hostA", 234).build();
```

Ideally I would be able to do something similar to this:

```java
ManagedChannelBuilder
   .forAddress("hostA", 234)
   .forAddress("hostA", 235)
   .forAddress("hostB", 234)
   .build();
```

and it would pick a working service from the list on each request.
It seems something like [this](https://itnext.io/on-grpc-load-balancing-683257c5b7b3) would be something similar in Go, but without the DNS resolution I would need.

Comment: You could only provide one address to the ManangedChannelBuilder. For failover, you can implement your own NameResolverProvider and register it into NameResolverRegistry. Your own NameResolverProvider will provide a resolver that can resolve the single address to mulltiple addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom name resolver factory:

```
class MultiAddressNameResolverFactory extends NameResolver.Factory {

    final List<EquivalentAddressGroup> addresses;

    MultiAddressNameResolverFactory(SocketAddress... addresses) {
        this.addresses = Arrays.stream(addresses)
                .map(EquivalentAddressGroup::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public NameResolver newNameResolver(URI notUsedUri, NameResolver.Args args) {
        return new NameResolver() {

            @Override
            public String getServiceAuthority() {
                return "fakeAuthority";
            }

            public void start(Listener2 listener) {
                listener.onResult(ResolutionResult.newBuilder().setAddresses(addresses).setAttributes(Attributes.EMPTY).build());
            }

            public void shutdown() {
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String getDefaultScheme() {
        return "multiaddress";
    }
}
```

And use it with the Round Robin algorithm as follows:

```
ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget("service")
            .nameResolverFactory(new MultiAddressNameResolverFactory(
                    new InetSocketAddress("hostA", 234),
                    new InetSocketAddress("hostA", 235),
                    new InetSocketAddress("hostB", 234)
            ))
            .defaultLoadBalancingPolicy("round_robin")
            .build();
```